# Segementation fault if accessing struct member in library function

Tags: c++, c, linux, segmentation-fault

Following Problem:
In my main program I declare struct variable and then pass the address to it to a library function (shared-object, compiled by me). The library function should initialize the struct, but it crashes with a segmentation fault. The crash happens when a member (type int) of the struct is set to 0. The problem doesn't happen if I set the same member in the main program.

Main program: C++ (compiled with g++)

```c
rnxctr_t tRNX;
tRNX.ephsat = 0;  // <-- works
init_rnxctr(&tRNX);
```

Library function: C (compiled with gcc)

```c
extern int init_rnxctr(rnxctr_t *rnx)
{
    gtime_t time0={0};
    obsd_t data0={{0}};
    eph_t  eph0={0,-1,-1};
    geph_t geph0={0,-1};
    seph_t seph0={0};
    int i,j;

    trace(3,"init_rnxctr:\n");

    rnx->obs.data=NULL;
    rnx->nav.eph =NULL;
    rnx->nav.geph=NULL;
    rnx->nav.seph=NULL;

    if (!(rnx->obs.data=(obsd_t *)malloc(sizeof(obsd_t)*MAXOBS ))||
        !(rnx->nav.eph =(eph_t  *)malloc(sizeof(eph_t )*MAXSAT ))||
        !(rnx->nav.geph=(geph_t *)malloc(sizeof(geph_t)*NSATGLO))||
        !(rnx->nav.seph=(seph_t *)malloc(sizeof(seph_t)*NSATSBS))) {
        free_rnxctr(rnx);
        return 0;
    }
    rnx->time=time0;
    rnx->ver=0.0;
    rnx->sys=rnx->tsys=0;
    for (i=0;i<6;i++) for (j=0;j<MAXOBSTYPE;j++) rnx->tobs[i][j][0]='\0';
    rnx->obs.n=0;
    rnx->nav.n=MAXSAT;
    rnx->nav.ng=NSATGLO;
    rnx->nav.ns=NSATSBS;
    for (i=0;i<MAXOBS ;i++) rnx->obs.data[i]=data0;
    for (i=0;i<MAXSAT ;i++) rnx->nav.eph [i]=eph0;
    for (i=0;i<NSATGLO;i++) rnx->nav.geph[i]=geph0;
    for (i=0;i<NSATSBS;i++) rnx->nav.seph[i]=seph0;
    rnx->ephsat=0;    // <-- segmentation fault
    rnx->opt[0]='\0';

    return 1;
}
```

Struct definition:

```c
typedef struct {        /* rinex control struct type */
    gtime_t time;       /* message time */
    double ver;         /* rinex version */
    char   type;        /* rinex file type ('O','N',...) */
    int    sys;         /* navigation system */
    int    tsys;        /* time system */
    char   tobs[7][MAXOBSTYPE][4]; /* rinex obs types */
    obs_t  obs;         /* observation data */
    nav_t  nav;         /* navigation data */
    sta_t  sta;         /* station info */
    int    ephsat;      /* ephemeris satellite number */
    char   opt[256];    /* rinex dependent options */
} rnxctr_t;
```

**Update**: Link to complete header file: [rtklib.h](https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/blob/master/src/rtklib.h)

**Some observations**

The problem only occures if I enable (define) some optional features (DENAGAL, DENACMP) of the library. But the differences to the "normal" version doesn't explain the problem at all. The only thing changing in the posted code is the `MAXSAT` definition.

**Update**:
I just realized, that a change of `MAXSAT` does change the size of structs inside `rnxctr_t` (e.g. `nav_t`)

With gdb I can see that the addresses of some members are different in the main program and in the function.
Main:

- &tRNX:        0x7ffffffc6e10
- &tRNX.nav:    0x7ffffffc7548
- &tRNX.ephsat: 0x7fffffffd290

Function:

- rnx:          0x7ffffffc6e10
- &rnx->nav:    0x7ffffffc7548
- &rnx->ephsat: 0x800000026ef8

This last point really confuses me, because I don't understand how that can happen.

best regards
Michael

Comment: is this C or C++ ?

Comment: Please post the definitions of `gtime_t` `obs_t` `nav_t` and `sta_t`. Please post the definitions of `MAXOBSTYPE` `MAXOBS` `MAXSAT ` `NSATGLO` `NSATSBS`. I think `for (i=0;i<6;i++)` should count up until `7`.

Comment: Do the options set change the size of the structure, and if so, do both the library and the calling code agree on the options that have been set?

Comment: It's possible your library and executable are being compiled with different 'padding' or 'alignment' settings. I don't know how to set this on your compiler, but it will be a switch/setting somewhere in the compiler options like "structure member alignment."

Comment: That's a big difference in address for the `ephsat` member.  Either the `nav_t` or `sat_t` structures have different definitions/sizes between the library (much larger) and your main program.

Comment: please provide a [mre] and choose to tag as either `c` or `c++` not both

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It's more likely that, due to a bug/UB somewhere, this function is overflowing its stack and overwriting the function arg `rnx`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: It's actually mixed, the main programm is C++ (compiled with g++) and the library is C (compiled with gcc).

Comment: better mention that in the question. questions correctly tagged as c and c++ are rather rare, thats why I asked

Comment: @KamilCuk: As some of this structs contains again other structs, I think it's simpler that i just give you a link to the header file: [link](https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/blob/master/src/rtklib.h)

Comment: `nav_t` has a bunch of arrays of length `MAXSAT`, so of course changing `MAXSAT` affects the layout of that struct, and you will need to recompile your library as well as the application code.  If that may happen often, you may want to redesign your data structures so that it is a run-time instead of compile-time option.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I actually recompiled both. The main program also with the 2 optional defines. I found the problem and will post it as the answer.   Regarding the library design: I don't like this kind of design as well, but it's an external library so ...

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. I just realized, that I used two different versions of rtklib.h. Which resulted in the different sizes of the rnxctr_t struct.

So in the end it was just my stupidity, but anyway thanks for your helpful comments.